# How can I get the last inserted Guid in Hibernate?

Tags: hibernate

Can anybody tell me how I can get the last inserted ID in Hibernate? In MySQL I used a query like `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()`.

Answer (score 1):

Why you need this is unclear but it should be possible using a native query. Something like that:

```
Integer lastId = (Integer) session.createSQLQuery("SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()")
    .uniqueResult();
```

Comment: Anonymous user suggested this edit: 
private Long lastId;
 
     lastId= ((BigInteger) sess.createSQLQuery("SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()").uniqueResult()).longValue();

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution this way:

```
lSession.flush();
long lAddGUID = lObjAddressTable.getUserGUID();
pObjAddressDetails.setUserGUID(lAddGUID);
if(0 != lAddGUID ){
                lRetVal = true;
}
```